# Subtracting a day from a date until a Boolean condition is met in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I currently have a pandas dataframe that contains a datetime column `df['date']` containing many dates and a Boolean column `df['bool']` that contains either 0 or 1.  The vast majority of  `df['date']` values are linked with `df['bool']` value of 1.  Rarely, some `df['date']` values are linked with `df['bool']` value of 0.

I want to create a new datetime column `df['date_offset']` that subtracts day(s) from `df['date']`, back to the most recent previous date where `df['bool'] = 1`

For example, I would like to turn this dataframe below...

```
import pandas as pd

rng = pd.date_range('2020-02-24', periods=17, freq='d')

data = {'date':  rng,
        'bool': [1, 1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['date','bool'])

print (df)

         date  bool
0  2020-02-24     1
1  2020-02-25     1
2  2020-02-26     1
3  2020-02-27     1
4  2020-02-28     1
5  2020-02-29     1
6  2020-03-01     0
7  2020-03-02     0
8  2020-03-03     0
9  2020-03-04     1
10 2020-03-05     1
11 2020-03-06     1
12 2020-03-07     0
13 2020-03-08     0
14 2020-03-09     1
15 2020-03-10     1
16 2020-03-11     1
```

Into something that looks like this...

```
    date    bool    date_offset
0   2020-02-24  1   2020-02-23
1   2020-02-25  1   2020-02-24
2   2020-02-26  1   2020-02-25
3   2020-02-27  1   2020-02-26
4   2020-02-28  1   2020-02-27
5   2020-02-29  1   2020-02-28
6   2020-03-01  0   2020-02-29
7   2020-03-02  0   2020-02-29
8   2020-03-03  0   2020-02-29
9   2020-03-04  1   2020-02-29
10  2020-03-05  1   2020-03-04
11  2020-03-06  1   2020-03-05
12  2020-03-07  0   2020-03-06
13  2020-03-08  0   2020-03-06
14  2020-03-09  1   2020-03-06
15  2020-03-10  1   2020-03-09
16  2020-03-11  1   2020-03-10
```

Any help would be most appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cumsum` on the `bool` to identify the blocks, then group the shifted date by those:

```
df['dateoffset'] = (df['date'].shift()
                        .groupby(df['bool'].eq(1)[::-1].cumsum()[::-1])
                        .transform('first') 
                        .fillna(df['date'].iloc[0] - pd.Timedelta('1D'))   # fill the first date
                   )
```

Or maybe simpler with `where` and `ffill`:

```
df['date_offset'] = df['date'].where(df['bool']==1).shift().ffill()
```

Output:

```
         date  bool dateoffset
0  2020-02-24     1 2020-02-23
1  2020-02-25     1 2020-02-24
2  2020-02-26     1 2020-02-25
3  2020-02-27     1 2020-02-26
4  2020-02-28     1 2020-02-27
5  2020-02-29     1 2020-02-28
6  2020-03-01     0 2020-02-29
7  2020-03-02     0 2020-02-29
8  2020-03-03     0 2020-02-29
9  2020-03-04     1 2020-02-29
10 2020-03-05     1 2020-03-04
11 2020-03-06     1 2020-03-05
12 2020-03-07     0 2020-03-06
13 2020-03-08     0 2020-03-06
14 2020-03-09     1 2020-03-06
15 2020-03-10     1 2020-03-09
16 2020-03-11     1 2020-03-10
14 2020-03-09     1 2020-03-08
15 2020-03-10     1 2020-03-09
16 2020-03-11     1 2020-03-10
```